# In C++/CX, why don't unreferenced hat ^ parameters generate warnings?

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-warnings, c++-cx, visual-c++-2012

I'm working on a Windows Store app and just bumped Visual Studio's warn level up to 4, so I've been fixing unreferenced parameter warnings.  In the process, I've noticed that unreferenced framework-managed parameters (^) do not generate a C4100 warning like other unreferenced "formal" parameters.  To illustrate what I mean:

```
void Method(CNonFrameworkManaged* pObject)
{
    // Warning C4100: 'pObject' : unreferenced formal parameter
}

void Method(CFrameworkManaged^ spObject)
{
    // No warning
}
```

Why is it that the second does not generate the warning?  And is there a way to turn on such warnings?  I want my code to appear consistent but tracking all of these down by hand would take days..

Note: I'm compiling my project without CLR support, but it seems like these should still be detectable.

Comment: "I'm compiling my project without CLR support" C++/CX and C++/CLI are mutually exclusive:  there is no way to combine C++/CX with "CLR support" within a single project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A hat type is a form of smart pointer, so each hat type has a destructor, which releases ownership of the pointed-to object.  While `spObject` is not referenced by name in your source code, the object is *referenced* by the compiler-generated call to the destructor at the end of the function.

When the compiler checks for unreferenced local variables, it finds this reference and does not issue the warning.  An ordinary (non-parameter) local variable must have a name, and it would be problematic if the compiler issued "unreferenced local variable" warnings for such local variables that exist solely to be destroyed (e.g., RAII types like `lock_guard`).  Warnings C4101 and C4189 are issued for unreferenced non-parameter local variables.  (Could the compiler treat parameters differently?  Possibly.  But it doesn't.)

Observe that C4100 is not issued for any parameter of a type that has a destructor:

```
struct A { };
struct B { ~B() { } };

void f(A a) { } // C4100 is issued for 'a'
void f(B b) { } // C4100 is not issued for 'b'
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer.  I believe it also begs the question of whether commenting out the name of the unreferenced ^ parameter would allow the compiler to remove the call to the smart pointer constructor/destructor?

Comment: @FrolickingFerret:  The behavior is the same regardless whether the parameter has a name.  That said, the compile can in many cases elide calls to AddRef and Release on a hat, because the compiler has full knowledge of how COM reference counting works (as opposed to, say, how shared_ptr reference counting works--to the compiler, a shared_ptr is like any other type).  I can write up a more in-depth explanation, but probably not before Friday.

Comment: This is very interesting.  It does make sense that the compiler would be able to apply elision to hat.  I hadn't really considered that vs. things like shared_ptr.  t